# How to add a context menu to the Catalog/Project/Folders-Entries in an AddIn for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: add-in, arcgis-pro-sdk

How to add a context menu to the Catalog/Project/Folders-Entries?

I use C# for creating an AddIn for ArcGIS Pro 3.1.

I got a feature request to add a new context menu entry to the "Catalog/Project/Folders"-entries.

After some searching I found a way to add a context menu button to the "Catalog/project/Maps"-Entries (refID="esri_mapping_map2DContextMenu").

How to add a context menu to the catalog pane?

Alternativly a list of all avalable refID's in ArcGIS Pro would be a good start for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...I solved my problem with the help of this Link: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-sdk-questions/daml-id-for-catalog-folder-context-menu/td-p/790840

This is the daml-text I used:

```
  <updateModule refID="esri_geodatabase_module">
      <menus>
          <updateMenu refID="egdbItemFeatureClassTypeMenu">
              <insertButton refID="ContextmenueChangeArcInfo_Menu1_Items_Button1" insert="after" placeWith="esri_projectItemPropertiesButton" />
          </updateMenu>           
      </menus>
  </updateModule>
```

Note that "ContextmenueChangeArcInfo_Menu1_Items_Button1" is the ID of a valid "ArcGIS Pro menu" which I added before.

Note also that this works only for "enterprise geodatabase feature classes and utility networks"

The best source of the "raw"-Ids can be found in the arc-gis-pro-git-lab here: https://github.com/esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/blob/master/DAML/ADGeoDatabase.daml.xml

After clicking the context menue my handler looks like this:

```
internal class Menu1_button1 : Button
{
    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        var info = FrameworkApplication.ContextMenuDataContext as GDBItem;
        MessageBox.Show("You chose the feature class: " + info.Name, FrameworkApplication.ActiveTool.Caption);
    }
}
```